# poky/meta/recipes-devtools/opkg-utils/opkg-utils_git.bb, do_unpack) failed with exit code '1'

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm new in using yocto. 
my environment is ubuntu 14.04, 
Build Configuration:

```
BB_VERSION        = "1.28.0"
BUILD_SYS         "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   "Ubuntu-14.04"
TARGET_SYS         "aarch64-fsl-linux"
MACHINE            "ls1043aqds"
DISTRO             "fsl-qoriq"
DISTRO_VERSION    "2.0"
TUNE_FEATURES      "aarch64"
TARGET_FPU        ""
```

I get the following error when running :
bitbake fsl-image-minimal
(on every call to bitbake  build )

```
=====================
 DEBUG: Running export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1001/keyring-an3Qaa/ssh"; export PATH="/opt/disk1/LS1043-Install/SDK/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/sources/poky/scripts:/opt/disk1/LS1043-Install/SDK/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_ls1043aqds/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-fsl-linux:/opt/disk1/LS1043-Install/SDK/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_ls1043aqds/tmp/sysroots/ls1043aqds/usr/bin/crossscripts:/opt/disk1/LS1043-Install/SDK/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_ls1043aqds/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/sbin:/opt/disk1/LS1043-Install/SDK/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_ls1043aqds/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/opt/disk1/LS1043-Install/SDK/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_ls1043aqds/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/sbin:/opt/disk1/LS1043-Install/SDK/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_ls1043aqds/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/bin:/opt/disk1/LS1043-Install/SDK/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/sources/poky/scripts:/opt/disk1/LS1043-Install/SDK/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/sources/poky/bitbake/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"; export HOME="/home/ymarko"; git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 branch --set-upstream master origin/master
| DEBUG: Python function base_do_unpack finished
| DEBUG: Python function do_unpack finished
| ERROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 128, output:
| fatal: the '--set-upstream' option is no longer supported. Please use '--track' or '--set-upstream-to' instead.
| 
ERROR: Task 854 (/opt/disk1/LS1043-Install/SDK/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/opkg-utils/opkg-utils_git.bb, do_unpack) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 306 tasks of which 298 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
Waiting for 0 running tasks to finish:
================================
```

Can you help please?

Comment: https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2017-October/038473.html

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your version of git to 2.7.3. I was having the same problem and this fixed it

Comment: the current version of git is 2.17.0. I'm running ububtu 14.04.even when doing apt update , and git install,  I get the message that I have the newest git version.

Answer (score 0):

You need [this patch](https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/145072/) in order to fix it.
Pay attention, you can't simply add "-to" as a suffix. The order of arguments also reversed.

Example how to use:

```
curl https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/145072/raw/ | git apply -v
```